# how to determine face similarity based on face landmark in an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, similarity, face

I was extracting face landmark based on dlib library

From the image I got have a list of tuple

```
P1 = [(277, 288), (248, 290), (182, 291), (210, 291), (230, 347)]
P10 = [(349, 291), (307, 278), (220, 247), (255, 260), (248, 346)]

P1
The left eyes on (277, 288), (248, 290)
The right eyes on (182, 291), (210, 291)
Nose tip on (230, 347)

P10
The left eyes on (349, 291), (307, 278)
The right eyes on (220, 247), (255, 260)
Nose tip on  (248, 346)
```

I was trying to use Euclidean Distance but I don't think is the correct approach for determine similarity from those landmark.

I was wondering how to get similarity value from those landmark that I have been extracting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem following way: you need to measure how similar are 5-gons (or 5-tuples of 2D points). If this is so you could probably use Procrustes analysis for that task. `scipy.spatial.procrustes` should do the trick:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.procrustes.html
You should look for `disparity`:

```
import scipy.spatial
d = scipy.spatial.procrustes(P10,P1)[-1]
print(d) #prints 0.001937599061578668
```

If I am not mistaken smaller that value more similar records. Please note that this is scale-insensitive i.e. 5-gon and say 2x times bigger 5-gon of same shape will give `0.0` (c.f. example in link).

Comment: Thank you @Daweo let me try first. Thanks. I will be back if this approach doesn't work